# Diode Circuit Analysis Problem 2

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes

[image]

According to my analysis, none of the options are correct. But the answer mentioned in my workbook is option B. 
[image]

In positive half cycle, I'm getting vo = vi.

[image]

And in negative half, vo = vi/2. This doesn't match any options.

Comment: Since this is obviously homework then you'll need to show your reasoning. Explain why each is wrong. Put the information in your question - not in the comments.

Comment: Check your case 1

Comment: "In positive half cycle, I'm getting vo = vi." ... Really? Is that what your positive cycle circuit drawing shows?

Comment: Below 1k is between gnd to gnd. So, it will be of no use.

Comment: The grounds are just confusing you... Just connect the two ground points together and worry about the voltage across the right 1K resistor.

Comment: @Trevor, you want to say that I should take -ve input terminal as reference gnd and then calculate potential difference between the 2 points across right 1K.

Comment: Corrrect .. that way you will be less likely to be confused. See 287001's redraw answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the diodes are ideal.

You should not allow the ground to confuse you. Redraw the circuit without it to see properly all wires. It's done here:

[image]

Now voltage B is the asked one.

Stop. You must to continue yourself.

Comment: Ok I got it. You took -ve input terminal as gnd and made the circuit simpler. Thanks @user287001.

Comment: @Nikhil I took NOTHING as ground. It's nonexistent in my drawing and thinking about how the circuit works. I have marked both ends for every essential voltage. The ground is the common reference point when one wants to write or talk about node voltages. Even then every voltage is between two nodes. Of course there's nothing wrong to think the most common end node of interesting voltages to be the ground.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, start by considering only the two peak input voltage cases.  Once you know what happens at each of the AC waveform peaks, you have a pretty good idea what happens for the rest of the waveform.

Draw out the circuit separately for each peak.  Substitute either a short or open for each diode, depending on whether it will be forward or reverse biased.  Note that all that will be left is the input voltage, some resistors, and the output voltage.  The output voltage should be obvious from inspection in each case.

Given the multiple-choice answers, choose the answer that matches what you get at the two peaks.  Note that all 4 choices differ in the peak results, so there should be no ambiguity.

Comment: Please check my attempt to the problem.